# Defining an array inside a function argument in C

Tags: c

Is there a way to define an array inside a function argument in C? Something like this:

```
void arraysomething(double vec[2]){
    //do something...
}

int main(){
    arraysomething({1.,2.});
    return 0;
}
```

I searched all over the place and found nothing.

Comment: C is a distinct language from C++. If the question is about C, the C++ tag is not appropriate.

Comment: It looks like you want [*compound literals*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/compound_literal).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you're looking for is called a **compound literal**:

```
arraysomething((double []){1.,2.});
```

The syntax looks like an initializer for an array or struct preceeded by what looks like a cast to the type in question.

Because you want to pass in array, the typename given should be `double []`, which means an array of unspecified size.  The actual size isn't needed because it is inferred from the number of elements in the literal.

Comment: i got this message:
stokes.c: In function 'main':
stokes.c:312:30: warning: excess elements in scalar initializer
   dotproduct2(A, (double){1.,2.});
                              ^~
stokes.c:312:30: note: (near initialization for '(anonymous)')
stokes.c:312:18: error: incompatible type for argument 2 of 'dotproduct2'
   dotproduct2(A, (double){1.,2.});
                  ^
stokes.c:45:8: note: expected 'double *' but argument is of type 'double'
 double dotproduct2(double A[2], double B[2]){

Comment: @JoãoPauloAndrade I made an edit.  It should be `(double [])`, not `(double)`.

Comment: @JoãoPauloAndrade Glad I could help.  Feel free to [accept this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) if you found it useful.